# TypeError: Network request failed android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, fetch, typeerror

I have following code in RN:

```
postToServer(){
  const requestBody = 'pin=1&status=false';
  return fetch('https://192.168.10.200/writeStatus.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    body: requestBody
  }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          console.log(responseJson);
        });
}
```

also i have following php file:

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
  print_r($data);
?>
```

When I run postToServer i receive:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: Network
>   request failed TypeError: Network request failed
>       at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (http://192.168.10.248:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=P:\sandbox\MojDom1\node_modules\expo\tools\hashAssetFiles:7854:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (http://192.168.10.248:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=P:\sandbox\MojDom1\node_modules\expo\tools\hashAssetFiles:12942:35)
>   ...(some lines here left - i have limit on links)
>       at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://192.168.10.248:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=P:\sandbox\MojDom1\node_modules\expo\tools\hashAssetFiles:2122:12)

Has anyone some suggestion?

Comment: In which os (android or ios) you are facing this issue or in the simulator or in real device?

Comment: This debugger message is from Chrome on Win10. I use exp to run app on my android 7.0 Huawei P10

Answer (score 0):

Add a `catch` method for errors:

```
postToServer(){
  const requestBody = 'pin=1&status=false';
  return fetch('https://192.168.10.200/writeStatus.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    body: requestBody
  }).then((response) => console.log(response))
}).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: The catch is what outputs this error `TypeError: Network request failed android`

Comment: I just add a `catch` to handle the error properly. `TypeError: Network request failed android` problem might be coming from the server, because the request can't connect successfully.

Comment: The app sends the `DELETE` request successfully, the server receives the request and processes it, but `.catch()` still fires. This happens only on android emulator and one specific `DELETE` request

Comment: Not quite sure on react native, but maybe there's a permission needed?

Comment: I don't think so because another `DELETE` request goes through just fine and API server isn't complaining.